# Get Smallest and Nearest Number to Zero - C#

Tags: c#

How to get Smallest and Nearest Number to Zero using C#?
For example the smallest and nearest DECIMAL (DOUBLE) number to zero maybe is 0.000009 on one PC and 0.0000000000000000001 on another.

I mean The Most Possible result by 1/THE_MOST_LONG_INTEGER.

How to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean to calculate your Machine Epsilon ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon ).

Which can be calculated in several ways, as example:

```
double machineEpsilon = 1.0d;

        do {
           machineEpsilon=  machineEpsilon/ 2.0d;
        }
        while ((double)(1.0 + machineEpsilon) != 1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you Saverio Terracciano, It seems your code is working fine but how to convert E-Number to Normal Number? For example how to get something like 0.00343424234 from a number like 3.434E?

Comment: @Stranger That is a normal number. It's a double, and acts as such. If you're asking how to change the manner in which it prints to screen, check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This gives you how to find the number closest to 1.0 (`1.11022302462516E-16`), but it seems the OP was asking for the number closest to 0.0 (`4.94065645841247E-324`).

Comment: The Machine Epsilon is the smallest increment you can add to a number without being rounded off on that machine. We could imagine it as the number closest to 0 that is not 0 (the smallest possible increment). The code starts from 1 and keeps being halved till it's non-incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but here's another possible method, trying to avoid iterations.
Based on the [floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#:%7E:text=Single%2Dprecision%20floating%2Dpoint%20format%20(sometimes%20called%20FP32),using%20a%20floating%20radix%20point.&text=E.g.%2C%20GW%2DBASIC%27s,bit%20MBF%20floating%2Dpoint%20format.), you can just generate the smallest fraction artificially.
In C#, being sizeof(double)=64:

- FOR NORMAL NUMBERS

  ```cs
   public double GetMinNormalFraction()
  {
    double inf =double.PositiveInfinity ;
    unsafe
    {
      ulong Inf_UL = *((ulong*)&inf);    
      ulong minFraction_UL = (Inf_UL ^ (Inf_UL << 1)) ^ ((1ul << 63) + 1ul);
      return  *((double*)&minFraction_UL); //2.2250738585072019E-308 in my computer                 
     }
  }
  ```
- FOR SUBNORMAL/DENORMAL NUMBERS

  ```cs
  public double GetMinDenormalFraction()
  {      
   unsafe
   {
      ulong unit = 1ul;
      return *((double*)&unit);  //4.94065645841247E-324 in my computer             
    }
  }
  ```

You can check if these are the smallest values using them as start point in machine-epsilon algorithm previously proposed by Saverio Terracciano (remembering to change to `while ( machineEpsilon > 0.0);` for denormal fractions)

**EDIT**

For the sake of completion but already out of the question, in case of needing the smallest fraction that can be added to a number, not just zero, the general method would be something like:

```cs
    public double GetMinFractionCloseTo(double number)
    {
        //check if number is a denormal/subnormal number
        if (double.IsNaN(number) || double.IsInfinity(number))
            return 0.0; // or throw Exception,etc

        unsafe
        {
            double inf = double.PositiveInfinity;
            ulong Inf_UL = *((ulong*)&inf);
            ulong Number_UL = *((ulong*)&number);

            bool isDenormal = (Inf_UL & Number_UL) == 0;

            if (isDenormal)
            {
                //MinFraction is always the same with denormals
                ulong unit = 1ul;
                return *((double*)&unit);
            }
            else //Normal number
            {
                //Detect if it's the last normal number close to zero    
                //(This can be skipped most of the times as it is very unlikely)                
                long maxLongValue = long.MaxValue;
                ulong ExcludeSign= *((ulong*)&(maxLongValue));
                ulong minFract_UL = (Inf_UL ^ (Inf_UL << 1)) | 1ul;
                bool isLimitToDenormal = ((minFract_UL ^ Number_UL) & ExcludeSign) == 0;

                if (isLimitToDenormal)
                {
                    //MinFraction is always the same with denormals
                    ulong unit = 1ul;
                    return *((double*)&unit);
                }
                else
                {
                    ulong ClosestValue_UL = Number_UL ^ 1ul;
                    double ClosestValue = *((double*)&(ClosestValue_UL));
                    return Math.Abs(number - ClosestValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```